# What does the day one patch do for Mass Effect 3 on Xbox 360?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I noticed that there is a patch (or possibly multiple patches) that installs when booting Mass Effect 3 for the first time. What does this patch do? Is it required? That is, if I did not have access to online updates, would my game potentially be broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://help.ea.com/article/mass-effect-3-day-one-patch

> **Patch notes**:
>
> - Fixed issue with disconnection during purchase flow
> - Fixed issue with 64Kbps connection.
> - Fixed issue with multiplayer consumables.
> - Fixed issue with multiple "Connection failed" messages sent to users.
> - Fixed hang when returning to Mission Computer from Squad in Pause
>   Menu when both the system language and in-game text language are set
>   to Japanese.
> - Fixed several minor DLC related issues
> - Fixed crash on Windows XP on minimum spec PC.
> - Fixed lighting and shading on minimum spec PCs.
> - Fixed potential crash when loading with quick resume.

Comment: Almost all of those look like PC-related issues, and the site itself refers to "pre-loading" which is definitely a PC thing. I'm not sure this list relates to the Xbox 360 patch.

Comment: Several of the issues affect the console -  specifically the multiplayer consumable issues. The text on the website says `Those of you playing Mass Effect 3 on console or those who did not pre-load`.